# Let $H\subset \mathbb{C}$ a closed set and $(z_n)\subset H$. Prove if $z=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_n$ then $z\in H$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

Let $H\subset \mathbb{C}$ a closed set and $(z_n)\subset H$. Prove if $z=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_n$ then $z\in H$

**My attempt**
Let $r>0$

Let $(z_n)\subset H$ a convergent sequence. As $H$ is a closed set, then $H$ contains all limits point.

By hypothesis we have exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|z_n-z|<r$

This implies

$B(z,r)\cap H\not =\emptyset$

Here, i'm stuck because i need $B(z,r)\cap H-\{z\}\not =\emptyset$ for say $z$ is a limit point. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $r>0$. Take, take $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies\lvert z-z_n\rvert<r$. Then either all $x_n$'s (with $n\geqslant N$) are equal to $z$, in which case $z\in H$, or there is at least one $z_n$ (with $n\geqslant N$) such that $z_n\neq z$. But then $z_n\in B(z,r)\setminus\{z\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $z\notin H$ then $z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus H=G$ where $G$ is open. And therefore there is a neighborhood of $z$ of type $B(z, r) \subseteq G$ and thus no point of $H$ lies in $B(z, r) $. But this contradicts the fact that $z_n\to z$ and $(z_n) \subseteq H$.